# How can I determine when two object is loaded?

Tags: javascript, image, vimeo

I'm loading an image

```
obgImage.onload = function ( imageReady = true )
document.getElementById('vimeo').onload= function() {   
                        videoReady = true;
}
```

What should i use to recognize when both of these are ready?

```
if(videoReady == true && pageReady == true){
        $('#loading').fadeOut();
    }
```

how do i make the if statement constantly check? I have query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var videoReady = false,
    imageReady = false,
    _ready = function() {
        if (videoReady && imageReady) {
            // do your code
        }
        else {
            // waiting for the other onload function to be called
        }
    };

obgImage.onload = function () {
    imageReady = true;
    _ready();
};

document.getElementById('vimeo').onload= function() {   
    videoReady = true;
    _ready();
};
```

Using this the ready function will be called two times if both elements will fire their onload function

Comment: i doubt that but glad i could help :)